# Java Html parser to extract specific data?

Tags: java, html-parsing, web-scraping

I have a html file like the following

```
...
<span itemprop="A">234</span>
...
<span itemprop="B">690</span>
...
```

In this i want to extract values as A and B.

Can u suggest any html parser library for java that can do this easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I favour **[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)** over **JTidy**. It has CSS-like [selectors](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html), and the documentation is much better, imho. With JSoup, you can easily extract those values with the following lines:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("your_url").get();
Elements spans = doc.select("span[itemprop]");

for (Element span : spans) {
  System.out.println(span.text()); // will print 234 and 690
}
```

Comment: I don't want to extract A and B but the other values 234 and 690

Comment: @vivek_jonam: Then use `text()` instead, which gives you the content of `span`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: ok. works. But can i get the values with A and B alone? there are other itemprop values like A1, C, E, etc.

Comment: Yes, there are two ways of doing this. 1) When you are iterating over each span element, you can check if `span.attr("itemprop")` equals `A` or `B`; 2) You can run two selects, one with `span[itemprop=A]` and the other with `span[itemprop=B]`.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsoup.org/

JSoup is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

[JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) is a confusingly named yet respected HTML parser.