# HTTP error fetching URL

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to parse this website with Jsoup: http://www.listofnewspapers.com/2014/04/site-map.html but I am getting this error:

> For 'http://www.listofnewspapers.com/2014/04/site-map.html': HTTP error fetching URL"

I believe the error is occurring at`connect(URL).get()`.

I printed the status code for debugging purposes, and I got `200`.

I tried with multiple other websites, and they connected fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JSoup error fetching URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780047/java-jsoup-error-fetching-url)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like user agents are filtered. Try setting up one:

```
Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla").get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Firefox userAgent:

```
.userAgent("Mozilla")
```

For example:

```
Jsoup.connect("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44349297/http-error-fetching-url").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```

Source: [Can Jsoup simulate a button press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508813/can-jsoup-simulate-a-button-press/7523425#7523425)